# Looking for an international weather API with rain probability

Tags: php, xml, api, weather

So yeah, I'm trying to build something like "Do I need an Umbrella", but it seems there's no API available to get rain probability data for locations other than the US.
Does anyone know any weather APIs that **do** provide rain probability in their (preferrably XML) responses?

Edit: I literally just discovered The Weather Channel's API, which /seems/ to have rain probability, but I'm not sure whether 100 requests per day will be enough, as I don't intend to pay 20$ per month to get that data. My server is already expensive enough.

Comment: Out of curiousity did you google your problem?

Comment: Of course I did, I wouldn't be asking here if I hadn't googled first. I've looked through at least 4 different APIs, registered for two more, not a single one of them could provide a percentage for rain.

Comment: @PeterW. there are at least 20.

Comment: Then please provide me with a free, XML-returning weather API that contains rain probability as a percentage, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"non US" is rather broad, but there are certainly places to get data.

To get you started, I know of a dutch one via http://gratisweerdata.buienradar.nl/ . You'd have to read dutch for the site, but that's quite sparse anyway

Available in xml ( http://xml.buienradar.nl/) or by lat/long http://gps.buienradar.nl/getrr.php?lat=52&lon=4

Comment: That one looks nice, though it's not really XML. :P So if I understood that correctly, "000" = 0% and "255" = 100% probability?

Comment: The first one (that isn't linkified, i'll fix that for you), the one that is called "xml", looks like Xml to me :)  )

Comment: What URL do I have to use to get my forecast in XML format? I tried http://xml.buienradar.nl/?lat=50.799846&lon=6.486958, but neither do I speak dutch, nor can I find my 0-255 values in there. :P

Comment: just plain " http://xml.buienradar.nl/ " gives me an xml, I haven't figured out the contents for you, but it looks like the weatherstations are listed first (current stats), and there is some sort of text only forecast. Maybe the other format is better.

Comment: I'll try using that page, hoping to get reliable results, as it seems to be the only **free** service providing rain data. Thanks :)